# about url rewriting and js extension with php

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm asking about the ability if I can use .js file as .PHP extension for example :

```
<script src="exampl.php">/script>
```

and if this method causes any problem ?

the second question is, if I make a url rewriting for making the extension to .js, how can I block the direct accès to example.php, and allow it when the visitor go to example. j's

I'm so sorry for my bad English, please help me and thank's to everyone how will participate :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? is it just to hide the JS file?

Comment: i don't want visitor know he is a php file

Comment: Yes I get that but why are you putting the JS into a php file?  for what purpose?

Comment: i use a platforme, and this one dos'nt suporte php ! i will do all with js, and the php is external in other server

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache as a web server it would be better to create a rewrite rule:
Create or edit .htaccess and add: RewriteRule ^example.js$ example.php [L]

For the second part you could check $SERVER_['HTTP_REFERER'] or use CSFR token method.

Comment: thank you for the reponse, he isn't possible to get the link  with htaccess and make a condition ?